# Dark and scabby spot on my kitten's nose

Tags: cats, health, skin-condition, ears-nose-throat

Hello everyone and thanks for reading this.

In the last days, I noticed that my kitten, he is three months old, has a black spot right above the nose (you can see in the photo) and I wonder what it is, have you ever seen something similar?

The first photo is from one week ago, the last is from today, the little spot has grown since the last week.

[image]

[image: Cat]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I think this is only a little bruise in the skin, it is most likely a result of your cat running into something during play.

It is not uncommon for this type of bruises to get darker during the first few days in the same way as bruises in people can do.

It does not look bad for now, but if it does not get better in a week you should take him to your vet.

The nose is an exposed part of your cat, so it gets easily bruised when cats play or fight their own reflection in windows or mirrors.

If there is any bleeding or discarge you need to take him to the vet.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I took him to the vet this morning and she confirmed what you are saying :)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like he may have scratched it with his nail. My dog had dark scabs all over his body similar to this color, but since the ones on your cat is not raised, I doubt it is the same condition. My dog's were bug bites.